# What swear word is gek*****?

Tags: german-to-english

Came across the following social media post and wondering what is the *gek*** * word being censored? And overall context translated to English, given that translators don't translate asterisked words.

> Gestern Mittag hat unsere jüngste den kompletten Boden voll gek*****. Nun habe ich ein komisches Gefühl im Bauch.
> Bringt es etwas Schonkost zu Essen, um gar nicht erst in die Lage zu kommen?

Comment: Note that it will help to understand that post correctly by fixing some spelling and grammar mistakes: _Bringt es etwas_**,** _Schonkost zu **e**ssen, ..._

Comment: I might add that there's quite some fair share of people on social media (especially above certain age thresholds in my personal observation) that use certain communication techniques in an (from average users perspective) odd way. In German social media, one if these techniques is excessive punctuation or this kind of censorship. Usually, one would either just write out the word or use a different one, since there's a plethora of other options to describe the same thing. The stilistic choice of going with the word but censoring it is fairly uncommon and imho not necessary/justified.

Comment: what other commonly censored words like *gek*** * immediately come to mind?

Comment: @kopaka: "Usually, one would either just write out the word or use a different one" - maybe the writers feel another (less drastic?) word might not accurately convey the "harshness" of the event. With that said, funnily, it is actually somewhat ambiguous what happened here, for strictly speaking, both "gekotzt" and "gekackt" would make sense concerning the context.

Comment: @user610620 In German, censoring is not common - either you choose a word and stick with it or you just go with another option. So basically nothing comes to my mind immediately. But as mentioned by the previous comment, it could be used as a stilistic device to convey or evoke certain emotions and to emphasize on one certain description for the event, while not feeling comfortable writing out the whole word, even though everbody knows or is supposed to know what it means (this is where I don't really understand this approach). On second thought, one example could be *f----* / ficken (to fuck)

Answer (score 13):

The word in question is probably *gekotzt* (vomited). Not a swear word, but vulgar. There are some less-vulgar expressions that mean the same, e.g.

> Sie hat sich übergeben.

but they're only used in formal language, and the vulgar variants are (in my opinion) much more common, even though people avoid writing them.

Using a less vulgar term in the above sentence also somewhat removes the disgust from the sentence:

> Gestern Mittag hat sich unsere Jüngste auf den Boden übergeben.

Comment: English vomit and puked aren't considered vulgar though. Are there some popular conventions surrounding the censorship of certain German words I'm not aware of?

Comment: @user610620 Vulgarity in German is traditionally a bit more connected to body excrements than in English, where vulgarity is a bit more connected to sexual stuff. Of course, this is changing over time and nowadays there is a strong impact of English on German in this regard.

Comment: @user610620 But you would probably agree that there is a difference between “puked” and “thrown up” in level of politeness? With the former being colloquial, bordering vulgar, and the latter perfectly acceptable?

Comment: Compare also "Das stört mich" vs "Das kotzt mich an!"

Comment: Another variant is "Sie hat den ganzen Boden vollgespuckt" which is an euphemic way to avoid "gekotzt" but surely means not "spitting" in common sense.

Comment: I'd say the most common expression that's neither too vulgar nor too formal is _brechen_. It doesn't work very well in this sentence though. »Gestern Mittag hat unsere jüngste gebrochen, den ganzen Boden voll.«

Comment: @leftaroundabout there is also (somewhat more formal) *erbrechen*, which is also not a good fit in the given sentence.

Comment: Sie hat __sich erbrochen__.

Comment: The answer suggests that the German word for "vomited" is more vulgar than the German word for "puked" (whatever it might be). I doubt this is true though.

Comment: @Allerleirauh: I am not convinced using "spucken" can be called euphemistic. Maybe it started as a euphemism, but nowadays, the "common sense" of "spucken" covers pretty much everything from spitting saliva to vomiting. In a statement like "Er spuckt.", without any further context, it is completely open whether this means "He is spitting." or "He is vomiting." In terms of register, I'd say "spucken" is exactly the neutral middle ground that sounds neither vulgar (like "kotzen" or "reiern") nor stilted (like "erbrechen" or "sich übergeben").

Answer (score 7):

For completeness reasons (even though I'm quite sure that was not the meaning): `gekackt` could be an equally valid statement, which means

> she shat on the floor

instead of

> she vomited on the floor

*(in the case of `gekotzt` mentioned in another answer)*

and provide a more reasonable explanation as to why it was censored.

Comment: Just from the sentence with gek*** this seems a valid interpretation but with the context of the two phrases afterwards this looks fairly unplausible to me.

Comment: Why would *gekackt* imply defecation here instead of vomiting? Are these meanings frequently used as perfect substitutes for the same German word?

Comment: @user610620 It does not imply defecation, that's the literal and only meaning of the word - the meaning of vomiting refered to the word "gekotzt" from the other answer. I will edit my answer to clarify!